# Logging exceptions in a highly multi threaded environment can lead to slow performance?

Tags: performance

I am facing high CPU load problem with my application. It happens like once in a day and restarting the tomcat server resolves it. I checked the DB stats but there are not any row locking or table locking issues.

But I do see multiple exception stack traces for run time exception in the tomcat log files.
My question is :-

Could this lead to slow performance in the scenario when multiple threads are trying to print exception stack traces in the same log file ??

Logically I think that only one thread can have access to the log file at a time !!

Comment: You're just seeing a manifest of the problem. If the log is full of exceptions it's most likely that what's causing the exceptions is the problem, no the log itself.

Comment: well.........its simply things like null pointer exceptions due to coding errors............I understand that we need to resolve them......but in the running application can the printing of stacktraces in a single log file by multiple threads cause slow performance ?